# error in object creation in perl

Tags: perl, oop

I have created a class called `person_b` and I am trying to create an object from the class. But it is throwing an error

> ```
> Can't locate object method "name" via package "main" at main_b.pl line 5.
> ```

#### person_b.pm

```
package person_b;

sub new {
    $class=shift;
    $self={};
    bless($self,$calss);
    return $self;
}

sub name {
    print "The name is ....\n";
}

1;
```

#### main.pl

```
use person_b;
use Scalar::Util 'blessed';

$per = new person_b();
print blessed($per), "\n";
$per->name();
```

#### output

```
main
Can't locate object method "name" via package "main" at main_b.pl line 5.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    bless($self,$calss);
                 ^^^^^
```

Typo?

Comment: ...and this is why you should _always_ `use strict; use warnings;` in your Perl code. It will automatically catch typos like this one for you.

Answer (score 4):

You have misspelled the name of your `$class` variable, resulting in `bless` trying to execute `bless $self, undef`

With `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` in place, this would have resulted in the useful error messages

> ```
> Use of uninitialized value $calss in bless at PersonB.pm
>
> Explicit blessing to '' (assuming package main)
> ```

which is why your program is showing

> ```
> Can't locate object method "name" via package "main"
> ```

- You *must always* add `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of every Perl source file that you write
- Your package names should begin with a capital letter, and the name of the file that contains them should match exactly
- You should avoid using the indirect object notation `new person_b`. It is much better written as `PersonB->new`

This code works fine

#### PersonB.pm

```perl
package PersonB;

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

sub new {
    my $class = shift;

    bless {}, $class;
}

sub name {
    print "The name is ....\n";
}

1;
```

#### main.pl

```perl
use PersonB;

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Scalar::Util 'blessed';

my $per = PersonB->new;
print blessed($per), "\n";

$per->name;
```

#### output

```
PersonB
The name is ....
```